# Excel VBA Array Column Sort

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still trying to figure out VBA and I have a query on sorting
I have a function call MatrixSort(matrix) that takes in a n1 x n2 matrix.
Is there any sorting function that VBA has that enables me to sort the matrix by count as seen below?

Inputting the box into Matrix Sort and getting the output below:
[image: Inputting the box into Matrix Sort and getting the output below]

Would appreciate if anyone can enlighten me on this

Thanks you very much!

Edit: 
Thanks to pEH for your code and logic. I have came up with the function based on your idea!
Although the code might not be efficient, I realized that there isn't an easy way to do CountA since the function will substitute empty cells as 0, as such I had to manually input "" and have the counter to ignore it.

```
'Sorts the Matrix into Decending Count Order
'Key Idea: Calculate count in each column and saves into ArrCount
'Then use Max(ArrCount) to find the max row count
'Use Match to get the column number with the max row count, then input this to first column under MatrixOut
'Kill the count that was copied under ArrCount(iMax) = -1 so that the next maximum count can be found
'Thanks to pEH from Stackoverflow for helping out
Function MatrixSort(matrix)

    Dim MatrixTemp As Variant

    Dim max_row As Integer
    Dim max_col As Integer

    Dim p As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim counter As Double 'Counts the number of filled range in matrix
    Dim iMax As Integer 'Stores the max count for sorting phase


    MatrixTemp = matrix

    'To preserve empty cells as empty instead of 0
    max_row = UBound(MatrixTemp, 1)
    max_col = UBound(MatrixTemp, 2)

    ReDim MatrixIn(1 To max_row, 1 To max_col)
    For i = 1 To UBound(MatrixTemp, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(MatrixTemp, 2)
            If MatrixTemp(i, j) = "" Then
                MatrixIn(i, j) = ""
            Else
                MatrixIn(i, j) = MatrixTemp(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i


    Set p = Application.WorksheetFunction

    'Counting of Each Columns
    ReDim ArrCount(1 To max_col) 'Counts filled rows in each column
    ReDim column_extract(1 To max_row) 'For CountA to work by counting each column individually

    For j = 1 To max_col
        For i = 1 To max_row
            If MatrixIn(i, j) <> "" Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next i
        ArrCount(j) = counter 'Stores the total count
        counter = 0 'Resets the counter before another loop
    Next j

    'Creation of Final Output Matrix
    ReDim MatrixOut(1 To max_row, 1 To max_col) 'For the Final Output

    'Column Sort
    For j = 1 To max_col
        iMax = p.Match(p.Max(ArrCount), ArrCount, False)

        For i = 1 To max_row
            MatrixOut(i, j) = MatrixIn(i, iMax)
        Next i
        ArrCount(iMax) = -1
    Next j

    MatrixSort = MatrixOut

End Function
```

Comment: please remember to include your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the following data:

[image]

To sort it by the count of filled rows in each column you just need to calculate that count `.CountA(RngIn.Columns(iCol))` for each column and save the results into an array `ArrCount`.

[image]

Then you can use `.Max(ArrCount)` to find the maximum row count and `.Match` to get the column number which is maximum. This is your first column so write it to the destination `RngOut`. Now we just need to kill the count that was already copied `ArrCount(iMax) = -1` so the next maximum can be found and copied to the next destination column … and so on …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MatrixSortColumnsByRowCount()
    'input range
    Dim RngIn As Range
    Set RngIn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F8")

    'output range
    Dim RngOut As Range
    Set RngOut = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B12:F18")

    'count filled rows in each column
    ReDim ArrCount(1 To RngIn.Columns.Count) As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 To RngIn.Columns.Count
        ArrCount(iCol) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RngIn.Columns(iCol))
    Next iCol

    'sort columns
    Dim iMax As Long
    For iCol = 1 To RngIn.Columns.Count
        iMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ArrCount), ArrCount, False)
        RngOut.Columns(iCol).Value = RngIn.Columns(iMax).Value
        ArrCount(iMax) = -1
    Next iCol
End Sub
```

The output then will be …

[image]